# Functors relationship in co and contra variance?

Tags: c#, covariance

I understand co and contra variance  by looking [Eric Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx).

There seems to be confusion in my understanding  in deriving functors from co and contra variance.

Can Contra variance exist without corresponding co-variance projection? Can we say IEnumerable and IComparer  are complement to each other? If we have Contra projection,can we drive co-projection?

Seems to be true to me but need to confirm?

Comment: In general generics in C# (unlike arrays) are not covariant nor are they contravarant.

Comment: with "complement" do you mean *dual*? There is a category theoretical side to this (where the concept is really easy) - so if you try to read enough into this to know where the terms come from you might understand more (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance)